# Classification of 2nd order quasi linear PDE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the second order quasi linear pde.

$$au_{xx}+2bu_{xy}+cu_{yy}=d.$$

Where $a=a(x,y,u_x,u_y)$. Similarly $b,c,d$

The characteristic curves $(f(s),g(s))$ are curves which satisfies $$ a g'^2-2bg'f'+cf'^2=0\cdots(1)$$

In my notes, its given eliminating s, we get

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\cfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-ac}}{a}$$

I didn't know how to eliminate $s$ in (1).

One way I can think of is using
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{g'}{f'}$$ assuming $f'(s)\neq0$

What to do if $f'(s)=0$ for some s?
Also what happens of both $a,c $ is 0 at a point (x,y)?

Answer (score 1):

If $f' = 0$ (and $a \ne 0$), (1) says $g'=0$.  So these curves would degenerate to points.

If $a=c=0$, then (1) says $f' g' = 0$, so either $f'=0$ or $g'=0$, i.e. the curve is either a horizontal or vertical straight line.

Comment: If f' is identically 0 then it degenerate to a point. What if the f' and g' are is 0 at a particular point $s_0$. For example $f'(s)=3s^2$  and  $g'(s) =6x^5$

Comment: That is tangent is 0 at some point $s_0$ for $(f(s),g(s))$